# Push array with new key to existing array

Tags: php, arrays

I am using

I want to create a new key to add auction details to a product.

```
<?php
        //Enter your code here, enjoy!
$resArr = array();
array_push($resArr, array("product" => "test1", "category" => "cat1"));
array_push($resArr, array("product" => "test2", "category" => "cat2"));
array_push($resArr, array("product" => "test3", "category" => "cat3"));

array_push($resArr[0]["auction"], array("name" => "auct1", "price" => "1"));

    
print_r($resArr);

// wanted result with array_push
$wantedArr = array(
    array(
        "product" => "test1", 
        "category" => "cat1",
        "auction" => array("name" => "auct1", "price" => "1")
    ),
    array(
        "product" => "test2", 
        "category" => "cat2",
        "auction" => array("name" => "auct1", "price" => "1")
    ),
    array(
        "product" => "test3", 
        "category" => "cat3",
        "auction" => array("name" => "auct1", "price" => "1")
    ),
);
print_r($wantedArr);
```

I would like to have the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product] => test1
            [category] => cat1
            [auction] => Array
                (
                    [name] => auct1
                    [price] => 1
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product] => test2
            [category] => cat2
            [auction] => Array
                (
                    [name] => auct1
                    [price] => 1
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [product] => test3
            [category] => cat3
            [auction] => Array
                (
                    [name] => auct1
                    [price] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You should be getting an error: `array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not adding to the `auction` as an array, you are just setting it to an array.  So...

```
$resArr[0]["auction"] = array("name" => "auct1", "price" => "1");
```

gives...

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [product] => test1
        [category] => cat1
        [auction] => Array
            (
                [name] => auct1
                [price] => 1
            )

    )
```